# '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) Issue with apache remotely connecting to mysql

Tags: mysql, apache-2.4, mariadb

Every now and then, I will get this issue where my Apache server cannot connect to my mariadb server remotely. It seems to occur at least once a month and I can't pinpoint the problem. It does however fixes itself for unknown reasons but then reappear weeks later.

In the apache logs (keep in mind: apache is on its own server), I get the following errors in the httpd error log:

```
[Wed Oct 21 11:23:57.883011 2015] [:error] [pid 30896] [client XX.XX.XX.XX:45324] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XX.XX.XX.XX' (99) in /home/domain.com/resources/config.php on line 15
[Wed Oct 21 11:23:57.883038 2015] [:error] [pid 30896] [client XX.XX.XX.XX:45324] PHP Warning:  mysql_select_db(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/domain.com/resources/config.php on line 16
```

When this issue does occur, it is intermittently, meaning sometimes when I reload the webpage, it works, other times it doesn't. I checked and saw that /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock exists and it is chmod 755 with mysql:mysql as the owner (on both servers, not sure why I would need to check on apache server as it is connecting remotely to mysql server but I did anyways).

I've already tried rebooting the mysql server twice with no luck, what can this be? Too many connections? Firewall issue? Open File Limits?

Comment: `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` is used for local connections only while remote connections used network sockets that are not mapped to the filesystem.

Comment: @Kondybas Interesting, would you know why the Apache server would try to connect locally when it shouldn't?

Comment: May be connection via filesocket is used as fallback when network connection is unavailable?

Comment: @Kondybas that might be true with mysql, anyways I believe it has something to do with the network/firewall between the two servers although both are located in the same data center. To save trouble, I just merged apache and mysql back to one server and all is working fine until I figure out what exactly was causing this.

Comment: The PHP code at this location does not do proper error checking, so it cannot recover gracefully from problems such as this. Be sure to have the developer fix this.